# MPI Check if communicator is MPI_COMM_WORLD

Tags: c, mpi, communicator

I need to check if a MPI communicator is `MPI_COMM_WORLD comm`. This means that all processors are within this communicator.

I tried this

```
int isCommWolrd(MPI_Comm comm) {
    int size_comm = 0;
    int size_comm_world = 0;
    MPI_Comm_size(comm, &size_comm);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size_comm_world);
    return (size_comm == size_comm_world);
}
```

Is it sufficient to check only the sizes of the communicator. Can there be a false positive of negative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MPI_Comm_compare()` and check the result is `MPI_IDENT`

> ```
> int MPI_Comm_compare(MPI_Comm comm1, MPI_Comm comm2, int *result)
> ```
>
> MPI_IDENT  results  if  and  only if comm1 and comm2 are handles for the same object (identical groups and same contexts).
>   MPI_CONGRUENT
>          results if the underlying groups are identical in constituents and rank order; these communicators differ only by  context. 
>   MPI_SIMILAR
>          results of the group members of both communicators are the same but the rank order differs. MPI_UNEQUAL results otherwise.

Your method can lead so false positive. For example, if you `MPI_Comm_dup(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm)`, then the resulting `comm` has the same size than `MPI_COMM_WORLD`, but it a different communicator.